# getting 4 ebs volumes to work with a windows server 2008 ec2 instance

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, hard-drive, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to have 4 ebs volumes attached to the same instance. One of the ebs volumes is the already attached root volume. Another one already attached, has its drive name set.

As soon as I attach the fourth volume, one of the volumes is not listed. Its like there was a 3 drives limit, but I can't find any information about it being that way and even found information saying you are supposed to be able to attached about 12 volumes (as many as the console management allows you).

I'm using the amazon's management console to attach the volumes. I also tried explicitly mapping the volume's drive letters in the amazon's ec2 config inside the instance.

Any way to get a fourth volume to show in the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

When attaching the ebs volume from the mgmt console, the volumes were coming online automatically (and initialized if necessary).

After attaching the fourth volume, for some reason that automatic behavior wasn't kicking in. I explicitely set the volume online with diskmgmt.msc, as mentioned on this [blog post](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/01/attaching-an-ebs-volume-to-ec2/).